# How to get CPU counters from stress-ng --perf?

Tags: linux, cpu, ubuntu-18.04, stress-testing, perf

I'm doing some stress testing on my CPUs, I'm using stress-ng as my stressor and I want to access my CPU cycles and Instructions. I use the flag --perf to get stress-ng to use perf events to measure information about the CPU. As you can see below I don't have access to CPU counters, like instruction calls and cache misses. I think it has something to do with admin access to the kernel. I am not really sure, is there someone who knows what I should do to make it work like the example at the bottom? 
**What I get:**

```
~$ sudo stress-ng --cpu 1 --perf --metrics-brief -t 10s
stress-ng: info:  [2611] dispatching hogs: 1 cpu
stress-ng: info:  [2611] successful run completed in 10.06s
stress-ng: info:  [2611] stressor       bogo ops real time  usr time  sys time   bogo ops/s   bogo ops/s
stress-ng: info:  [2611]                           (secs)    (secs)    (secs)   (real time) (usr+sys time)
stress-ng: info:  [2611] cpu                2537     10.06      9.94      0.05       252.25       253.95
stress-ng: info:  [2611] cpu:
stress-ng: info:  [2611]                        746 Page Faults User               74,16 /sec 
stress-ng: info:  [2611]                          1 Page Faults Kernel              0,10 /sec 
stress-ng: info:  [2611]                         76 System Call Enter               7,56 /sec 
stress-ng: info:  [2611]                         75 System Call Exit                7,46 /sec 
stress-ng: info:  [2611]                          5 TLB Flushes                     0,50 /sec 
stress-ng: info:  [2611]                         20 Kmalloc                         1,99 /sec 
stress-ng: info:  [2611]                          1 Kmalloc Node                    0,10 /sec 
stress-ng: info:  [2611]                         94 Kfree                           9,34 /sec 
stress-ng: info:  [2611]                        125 Kmem Cache Alloc               12,43 /sec 
stress-ng: info:  [2611]                          1 Kmem Cache Alloc Node           0,10 /sec 
stress-ng: info:  [2611]                        188 Kmem Cache Free                18,69 /sec 
stress-ng: info:  [2611]                        696 MM Page Alloc                  69,19 /sec 
stress-ng: info:  [2611]                          2 MM Page Free                    0,20 /sec 
stress-ng: info:  [2611]                    5 938 RCU Utilization               590,32 /sec 
stress-ng: info:  [2611]                         24 Sched Migrate Task              2,39 /sec 
stress-ng: info:  [2611]                          0 Sched Move NUMA                 0,00 /sec 
stress-ng: info:  [2611]                        196 Sched Wakeup                   19,49 /sec 
stress-ng: info:  [2611]                          0 Sched Proc Exec                 0,00 /sec 
stress-ng: info:  [2611]                          0 Sched Proc Exit                 0,00 /sec 
stress-ng: info:  [2611]                          0 Sched Proc Fork                 0,00 /sec 
stress-ng: info:  [2611]                          0 Sched Proc Free                 0,00 /sec 
stress-ng: info:  [2611]                          0 Sched Proc Hang                 0,00 /sec 
stress-ng: info:  [2611]                          0 Sched Proc Wait                 0,00 /sec 
stress-ng: info:  [2611]                         44 Sched Switch                    4,37 /sec 
stress-ng: info:  [2611]                          0 Signal Generate                 0,00 /sec 
stress-ng: info:  [2611]                          1 Signal Deliver                  0,10 /sec 
stress-ng: info:  [2611]                        304 IRQ Entry                      30,22 /sec 
stress-ng: info:  [2611]                        304 IRQ Exit                       30,22 /sec 
stress-ng: info:  [2611]                    3 098 Soft IRQ Entry                307,98 /sec 
stress-ng: info:  [2611]                    3 098 Soft IRQ Exit                 307,98 /sec 
stress-ng: info:  [2611]                          0 Writeback Dirty Inode           0,00 /sec 
stress-ng: info:  [2611]                          0 Writeback Dirty Page            0,00 /sec 
stress-ng: info:  [2611]                          0 Migrate MM Pages                0,00 /sec 
stress-ng: info:  [2611]                         44 SKB Consume                     4,37 /sec 
stress-ng: info:  [2611]                          0 SKB Kfree                       0,00 /sec 
stress-ng: info:  [2611]                          0 IOMMU IO Page Fault             0,00 /sec 
stress-ng: info:  [2611]                          0 IOMMU Map                       0,00 /sec 
stress-ng: info:  [2611]                          0 IOMMU Unmap                     0,00 /sec
```

**What I want:**

```
# stress-ng --matrix 40 -t 30s --times --perf --tz --metrics-brief
stress-ng: info:  [12734] dispatching hogs: 40 matrix
stress-ng: info:  [12734] cache allocate: default cache size: 22528K
stress-ng: info:  [12734] successful run completed in 30.66s
stress-ng: info:  [12734] stressor      bogo ops real time  usr time  sys time   bogo ops/s   bogo ops/s
stress-ng: info:  [12734]                          (secs)    (secs)    (secs)   (real time) (usr+sys time)
stress-ng: info:  [12734] matrix         2057213     30.02   1187.60      1.55     68534.05      1729.99
stress-ng: info:  [12734] matrix:
stress-ng: info:  [12734]          2,418,977,858,680 CPU Cycles                    78.88 B/sec
stress-ng: info:  [12734]          3,616,346,898,160 Instructions                   0.12 T/sec (1.495 instr. per cycle)
stress-ng: info:  [12734]                216,338,520 Cache References               7.05 M/sec
stress-ng: info:  [12734]                 30,689,400 Cache Misses                   1.00 M/sec (14.19%)
stress-ng: info:  [12734]            457,662,770,480 Branch Instructions           14.92 B/sec
stress-ng: info:  [12734]              3,541,729,200 Branch Misses                  0.12 B/sec ( 0.77%)
stress-ng: info:  [12734]             29,326,176,200 Bus Cycles                     0.96 B/sec
stress-ng: info:  [12734]          2,463,405,104,320 Total Cycles                  80.33 B/sec
stress-ng: info:  [12734]                      6,240 Page Faults Minor            203.49 sec
stress-ng: info:  [12734]                          0 Page Faults Major              0.00 sec
stress-ng: info:  [12734]                    103,360 Context Switches               3.37 K/sec
stress-ng: info:  [12734]                      1,280 CPU Migrations                41.74 sec
stress-ng: info:  [12734]                          0 Alignment Faults               0.00 sec
stress-ng: info:  [12734]                      2,360 System Call Enter   
...
```

Comment: It's working for [me](https://pastebin.com/8QSGtdaT). I have an Ubuntu 16.04 laptop. What is your CPU model? Mine is an Intel i7-4810MQ.

Comment: I have an Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3210M @seldak, do you think the CPU model is the cause?

Comment: I doubt it, I was checking you had a recognized CPU manufacturer. You can try checking if `perf` by itself works, just to be sure. `perf list` should list your supported HW events. If no hardware events show up, it is indicative that they are not enabled in your kernel. Try `zcat /proc/config.gz | grep CONFIG_HW_PERF_EVENTS` to be sure.

Comment: I discovered that perf command wasn't installed, so I installed it through linux-tools-generic and got it to work, It showed all HW events I wanted. So I  tried the zcat command, but I didn't have a config.gz file. @seldak Thanks for the help anyway!

Comment: You just found a bug in `stress-ng` package on Ubuntu 18.04. linux-tools-generic isn't mentioned in stress-ng [dependencies](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/devel/stress-ng). Might be worth a bug report on launchpad if you have the time :)

Comment: stress-ng uses the perf interfaces and does not use any linux-tools-generic perf tools whatsoever.